# initialize a class with return values of a function in c++

Tags: c++, class

I have to classes, and I want to initialize first class with return values of a function of the second class. To clarify, consider this

```
class Bet
{
private:
  unsigned int money;
  char result; // one of o, e, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
public:
  Bet(unsigned int m = 0, char r = '0') : money{m}, result{r} {}
  unsigned int getMoney() const { return money; }
  char getResult() const { return result; }
};

class Player
{
protected:
  string name;
  unsigned int  money;
  double betMoney;
  char result;

public:
  Player(string _name="NONE", unsigned int  _money=0)
     :name{_name}, money{_money} {}
  ~Player();
  double getMoney() const {return money;}  
  string getName() {return name;}
  virtual tuple<unsigned int, char> bet();
  virtual void win(double winMoney);
};

class HumanPlayer : public Player
{
public:
  HumanPlayer(string _name, unsigned int _money = 1000):Player(_name,_money) {}
  void win(double winMoney) override
  {
    money = money + result + winMoney;
  }

  tuple<unsigned int, char> bet() override
  {
    cout << "Player" << name << ", your bet:" 
     << "amount of money (you have " << money << "):" << endl;
    cin >> betMoney;
    while (betMoney > money)
    {
      cout << "Player" << name << " only has " << money << " Euros):" << endl;
      cin >> betMoney;
    }
    money-=betMoney;
    cout << "result (o[dd], e[ven], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6):";
    cin >> result;
    return {money,result};
  }
};
```

and I want to initialize Class Bet with bet function of class HumanPlayer like this

```
 Player* p = new Player{"John,1000);  // p is a pointer to an object of Player class      
 Bet b{p->bet()};
```

the class player first initialized with a pointer and then call bet function by which class Bet is initialized. I used tuple, but it did not work. I can not change class Bet, but I should modify class Player, HumanPlayer, and ComputerPlayer.

Comment: There's no instance `p` points to: `Player* p{};` -> `Player* p = new Player();`

Comment: Your constructor takes two arguments, but `bet` only returns one object. You need to write a constructor that takes the `tuple`.

Comment: `Player::bet()` (and overloads) returns a value of type `tuple<unsigned, char>`.   `Bet` therefore needs a constructor that accepts an argument of that type.   A `tuple<unsigned, int>` is not automatically converted to a pair of arguments, as expected by your existing constructor.

Comment: I only tried to do it with tuple. I know it does not work, the problem is how can I do it, I mean initialize Bet class with return argument of bet function of class Player.

Comment: Please add all requirements, including what you're supposed to do and what you're not allowed to do, to the question. There is no point in answering if you're going to add restrictions as they come up.

Comment: @molbdnilo I changed the question and added some details.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of `bet`.

In `Player`:

```
virtual ~Player() {}

virtual Bet bet() = 0;
```

In `HumanPlayer`:

```
Bet bet() override
{
    cout << "Player" << name << ", your bet:" 
     << "amount of money (you have " << money << "):" << endl;
    cin >> betMoney;
    while (betMoney > money)
    {
      cout << "Player" << name << " only has " << money << " Euros):" << endl;
      cin >> betMoney;
    }
    money-=betMoney;
    cout << "result (o[dd], e[ven], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6):";
    cin >> result;
    return Bet {money,result};
}
```

Comment: I can not change Bet class. I should modify bet function in HumanPlayer Class.